# How user input inserts into database

Tags: php, html

Only a project. I need to connect user input for a website, to my database.
I have the following files: index.php, submitsleep.php and template.php

this is submitsleep.php

```
<?php
  include('template.php');

  $hoursofsleep = $_POST['hoursofsleep'];
  $daytimenaps = $_POST['daytimenaps'];
  $bedtime = $_POST['bedtime'];
  $getuptime = $_POST['getuptime'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO sleep4project (hoursofsleep, daytimenaps, bedtime, 
  getuptime) VALUES ('$hoursofsleep', '$daytimenaps', '$bedtime', 
                     '$getuptime');";mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header('Location:index.php');
?>
```

This is my template file that I include in my index.php where my user input code is at.

```
<?php
  session_name('Website');
  session_start();
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "grace18";
  $pwd = ""; // my password
  $db = "grace18_db"; 
  $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
  $navigation = <<<END
  <nav>

    END;

  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']))
  {
    $navigation .= <<<END

    END;
  }
  $navigation .= '</nav>';
?>
```

In my index.php I have:

```html
<!-- Nav Item - Sleep Collapse Menu -->
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSleep" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSleep">
    <i class="fas fa-bed"></i>
    <span>Sleep</span>
  </a>
  <div id="collapseSleep" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSleep" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
      <form action="submitsleep.php" method="post">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Hours of sleep:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hoursofsleep" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Hours of sleep" value="">
        </div>
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Daytime naps:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daytimenaps" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Daytime naps" value="">
        </div>
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Bed time:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bedtime" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Bed time" value="">
        </div>
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Get up time:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="getuptime" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Get up time" value="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit_button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

But user input does not get added into my table sleep4project in the database.

Comment: Does it make empty rows in database?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable- SQLIA. You make use of mysqli but forgot to use prepared statement.

Comment: It doesn't create anything in the database at all. 
The code is for a project website, so it does not need to have security.

Comment: You should use isset function to check posted data is set or not and also you should check posted data is empty or not. you should do it all posted data which is required. for example: isset($_POST['hoursofsleep']) and also empty($_POST['hoursofsleep']) . Above this example, isset() return true is hoursofsleep key is exists or is set otherwise return false and also empty() return true when it empty otherwise return false

Comment: Could you please add any HTML containing your form of inputs so that we can see that data is being managed correctly toward your PHP (back-end) side? For more information see [MCVE]

Comment: try to change mysqli_query($conn, $sql) to mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql). Your $conn was wrong here

Comment: I have added HTML code now for the form

Comment: If i change to mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_query' (T_STRING)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Can you reduce the code to the relevant parts?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is vulnerable to SQLIA and mysqli allows you to make prepared statements. So, for security reason please make use of parepared statement where user inputs need to be stored database.

First you need to check your connection is not working or not

```
// check validation
if(empty($_POST['hoursofsleep']) || empty($_POST['daytimenaps']) || empty($_POST['bedtime']) || empty($_POST['getuptime'])) {
    die('all data required');
}
// create new connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Now at inserting side

```
 try {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO sleep4project (hoursofsleep, daytimenaps, bedtime, getuptime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    // I consider all are string you can change as per your neeed
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $hoursofsleep, $daytimenaps, $bedtime, $getuptime);

    // now set the value of you binding varables
    $hoursofsleep = $_POST['hoursofsleep'];
    $daytimenaps = $_POST['daytimenaps'];
    $bedtime = $_POST['bedtime'];
    $getuptime = $_POST['getuptime'];

    //Now execute your query by
    $stmt->execute();
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
}
```

Comment: Not checking for null or empty value is bad practice though for as far as I am aware.

Comment: If I put the two codes in my submitsleep.php file, and add include('template.php') before it, I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mysqli' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: sorry, I was in hurry so I have mistake in code around if statement ... now fixed please check

Comment: Ok i will reply you after 1hr .. am leaving now.. cu then

Comment: @Barrosy I update my answer as per your suggestion. Thanks for suggestion